# MongoDB collection create index not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to implement a simple search engine on my application and here's the api I made :

```
global.db.collection("pages").createIndex({"datas.content":"text"});
global.db.collection("pages").find({$text: {$search: req.body.query}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  res.json(result);
});
```

And here's my document structure :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd176aee5b87c095cfa30ba"),
    "code" : "af34e870-70c1-11e9-9ba8-eb8f4152101a",
    "datas" : {
        "content" : "Donec ante sapien, gravida id risus eget,"
    },
    "tags" : null
}
```

But when I call the `api` I always get `null` as a result, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `toArray` passing a `null` result suggests that an error has occurred. Check for those.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem for [Full-Text Search in MongoDB](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835)

But what's left is doubtful is the information coming to API. Hope your request is `POST` and inside it a key with the name of `query`. But if your request is a `GET`, you should use `{$search: req.query}}` and you should check the data that coming from client side is ok!

OR in `res.json(result)` result is not `JSON`.